# can't figure out why part of UV map is stretching

Tags: texturing, uv

I am modeling a cabin in blender right now and while I was in the middle of texturing, I noticed that the texture is stretched only on one specific face, so I looked into it and found out that the UV map was stretching it for some reason, But my problem is, I can't find out WHY.  And more importantly, how to fix it.

Here is an image of the stretched face:
[image]

And here is an image of the stretched UV:
[image]

I've already tried adding seams,  I made sure there were no n-gons.  I'm not sure what else to do to fix it.

any help is appreciated!

Here is the file for anyone who wants it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZV1zwGXUIr2Z8AdgQBNfAvJRliQMHGam/view?usp=sharing

(I couldn't upload it with any of the textures because the file was too big)

Comment: What projection are you using to unwrap?

Comment: just the standard UV unwrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topology is messy, when you unwrap Blender has no choice but to connect the faces, which gives stretched UVs. If we take a look at the corner we first see that the vertices are not connected, the face continues inwards:

[image]

Delete it, then you see that this edge floats:

[image]

Delete as well and cut again with the knife:

[image]

Now delete the face on the left and see, you have inner faces, delete them:

[image]

Now fill the hole:

[image]

Now unwrap again and your issue has disappeared:

[image]

There may be some other issues in your topology though, make sure that you don't have other inner faces, floating edges, etc... Another way to fix your UV problem quickly would have been to select one of the faces, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Similar Normal* to select all the faces of this wall, switch to side view and <kbd>U</kbd> > *Project From View*, but it would have left all the topology issues:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked!  I had no idea the face wasn't connected to the other ones.